# Center carousel on responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My carousel has a bad alignament on small screens, but on laptop/desktop it`s fine. I`ll attached for you a screenshot and my css code.

Thanks a lot.

```
.MultiCarousel { margin-right:15px; margin-left: 15px;float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px; width: 100%; position:relative; }
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner { transition: 1s ease all; float: left; }
    .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { float: left;}
    .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { text-align: center; padding:10px; margin:10px; background:#f1f1f1; color:#666;}
.MultiCarousel .leftLst, .MultiCarousel .rightLst { position:absolute; border-radius:50%;top:20% ; }
.MultiCarousel .leftLst { left:0; }
.MultiCarousel .rightLst { right:0; }

    .MultiCarousel .leftLst.over, .MultiCarousel .rightLst.over { pointer-events: none; background:#ccc; }
```

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: try using margin:auto;left:0;right:0; if possible share the code.

Comment: next time post the entire code so we can help you easier

Comment: if possible share the code

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `left:` and `right:` rather take a look at this

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

all you need to do on the carousel is **`margin: 0 auto;`**